# Парсинг безымянных блоков в AngleSharp

Tags: c#, парсер, anglesharp

Подскажите пожалуйста как из этого блока выбрать только вот это : 8.85 р / шт

```
<div class="price">
      <!--Розничные цены-->
     <!-- 1 -->
        <span style='font-size:12px;color:#313131;'>дисконт</span> <span class="discount-price">8.60</span><br>
        8.85 р / шт     
    <!--/Розничные цены--> 
          </div>
```

Сейчас пробую так: `var price = document.Result.QuerySelectorAll(@".price");`
Но в результате выводится все, что находится в блоке `<div></div>`

Comment: Я задавал на enSO такой же вопрос, см. [How to parse text from anonymous block in AngleSharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42736218/5752652)

Comment: @AK Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я дал вам ссылку на [вопрос на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42736218/5752652), там есть красивый вариант (через чтение AngleSharp'ом безымянных блоков CSS) и мой варварский в вопросе (вырезанием всех "лишних" нод).

В вашем случае начните с чего-то типа:

```
var parser = new HtmlParser();

var document = parser.Parse(@"<div class=""price"">
      <!--Розничные цены-->
     <!-- 1 -->
        <span style='font-size:12px;color:#313131;'>дисконт</span> <span class=""discount-price"">8.60</span><br>
        8.85 р / шт     
    <!--/Розничные цены--> 
          </div>");

var priceBlocks = document.QuerySelectorAll("div.price");

foreach (var block in priceBlocks)
{
    var element = block.ChildNodes.First(o => o.NodeType == AngleSharp.Dom.NodeType.Text && o.TextContent.Trim() != "");

    element.Text().Trim().Dump();
}
```

Linqpad говорит, что вам вполне сойдёт для начала:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Писал наспех, поэтому подразумеваю, что вы понимаете, что такое linq.

Comment: Гм. В xml/html такие блоки называются _текстовые узлы_ - text node. `NodeType.Text` - оно и есть. Думаю, термин из css не очень подходит.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо за уточнение, позже перепишу ответ с учётом замечания.